# MImekit - why do we need database to use for certificate storage and DefaultSecureMimeContext?

Tags: mimekit

While I am aware this may be a silly question but if someone can provide pointers it would be really good.
This is with reference to MimeKit documentation given here.

http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Working-With-SMime.htm

I can see there are overloads for signing and encrypting that work without having a context or database.  My question is - What is the role of database for certificate storage?  Is there a performance difference if we use a database and if we do not use one?

Answer (score 3):

> While I am aware this may be a silly question

It's not a silly question, it's actually a good question. I'm surprised no one has asked it until now...

The encryption, decrypting, signing and verifying methods, whether they take a context parameter or not, all use a context internally. The methods that don't take a context parameter just use the default context (which is why there are [CryptographyContext.Register](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Overload_MimeKit_Cryptography_CryptographyContext_Register.htm) methods).

As far as why a database is used in the [DefaultSecureMimeContext](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_Cryptography_DefaultSecureMimeContext.htm) implementation goes... the certificates and private keys need to be stored *somewhere* and in some sort of format on disk, right? Why not a database?

**Why not the X509Store that Windows uses by default?**

Because Mono doesn't implement the X509Store class so it's not a viable cross-platform solution.

If you want to use the Windows X509Store, though, you can - just use the [WindowsSecureMimeContext](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_Cryptography_WindowsSecureMimeContext.htm).

You don't even need to subclass the WindowsSecureMimeContext. Just Register it and you are Good-to-Go(tm).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Secure Mime Context inherits from WindowsSecureMimeContext

and storage it in memory using X509Certificate2Collection

override Import method to load the certificate in the collection also override the GetSignerCertificate and GetRecipientCertificate to search the certificate in the collection